# Google drive API (v2) unable to download few files (with extension xlsx,pdf)

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to download documents/files store in google drive using google drive API version (V2). though I am able to download files successfully except few that are failing with Bad request.
I have tried rest API approach

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get

as well as native SDK method

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive.
Code snipped to download non google file:

```
public InputStream download() throws IOException {
    HttpRequest httpRequest = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()));
    try {
        return httpRequest.execute().getContent();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        log.warn("File '{}' could not be downloaded, illegal argument: {}", file.toString(), e.getMessage());
        throw e
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

and Native SDK method

```
 public InputStream download() throws IOException {
        return driveService.files()
                .get(file.getId())
                .executeMediaAsInputStream();
}
```

But nothing working and there is nothing in error logs except below:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
> Bad Request
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
> at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1067)
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMedia(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:380)
> at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Get.executeMedia(Drive.java:5765)
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMediaAsInputStream(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:523)
> at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Get.executeMediaAsInputStream(Drive.java:5760)

I have also reported this issue as bug : https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/issues/1910

Comment: Can you share the code you are using without the id's and the type of files that are failing? Could it be this: `To download Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides use files.export instead.` Mentioned on the [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get) docs?

Comment: It is not issue with Google Documents. I am having issue with one file with .xlsx extension. Though i am able to download files (pdf,xlsx ...) with content. But sometime it fails for the file extension (xlsx,pdf), For Google workspace document, i am using export link and for other files , using download url

Comment: Why are you using V2? Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Product is using V2 that we need to support. I have added code in question

Comment: Have you tried using other languages like python or Apps Script to download this failing files? To check if this is not only related to Java.

Answer (score 1):

Its a little hard to help as you still have not included a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  However by looking at this method you are calling by passing the DownloadUrl link I suspect you have forgotten to check if it is null.   Not all files have a download Url link in some cases it is null.  If I recall with the v2 api binary type files will not have a download link.  All files that are not Google drive mime type will be considered binary type files.  Google sheet will have a download url,  xlsx will not.

```
new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()
```

May I suggest that you use the supplied download method rather than relying on the downloadUrl

```
String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId)
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

[File.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get) responds with the download stream of the file itself. You don't need to do an export links on an xlsx file its already a binary file. You export a google sheet to xlsx. Try using the example given for all but internal google [mime types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/mime-types) those you should be preforming an export on.

For more information please consult [Manage downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-downloads)

I strongly suggest that you switch to the V3 of the api soon.

Comment: Since i can't share complete code .We are verifying download URL before calling above method and for Google sheet or google workspace document , we are using export links

Comment: Its hard to help you without seeing what you are doing.   This is the best i can do.  Edit your question and include [Example].  File.get responds with the download stream of the file itself.  You don't need to do an export links on an xlsx file its already a binary file. You export a google sheet to xlsx.  Try using the example given for all but internal google [mime types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/mime-types) those you should be preforming an export on.

Comment: Now, I cannot download the same file using Google API Explorer. I'm getting 400 (Bad Request). I have also tried Google Drive UI, When I click to download a file as xlsx or any other format just nothing happens. this Google Workspace spreadsheet file contains lots of images and 12 tabs.

Comment: Explorer doesn't allow you to download files.  you need to use your code

Comment: I have also tried it with Google drive UI.When I click to download a file as xlsx  , a message appear in left bottom "converting to excel" then it disappear and no thing happens . this Google Workspace spreadsheet file contains lots of images and 12 tabs